# Failed building wheels for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype

```
  checkdep_freetype2.c
  src/checkdep_freetype2.c(5): fatal error C1189: #error:  "FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required. You may set the MPLLOCALFREETYPE environment variable to 1 to let Matplotlib download it."
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Using python version 3.10.11

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install/remove packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.